# convert Unix time to firstore timestamp in a cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, google-cloud-functions

**Step 1**: I am reading from a weather provider and they provide sunrise time in Unix, UTC - something like "1565616151" 
**Step 2**: I am converting this to Javascript Date using "var sunrise = new Date(openWeatherData.sys.sunrise*1000)"
**Step 3**: I need to store this in my firestore document as Timestamp. But I am unable to convert the date from Step 2

I have tried using:

```
admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(sunrise)
```

This gives me the below error on console

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined
>
> at Function.fromDate (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/timestamp.js:64:42)

Relevant code:

```
request(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log('Successfully retrieved from openweather');
      var openWeatherData = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(`Output from OpenWeather for Sunrise:${openWeatherData.sys.sunrise}` );
      var sunrise = new Date(openWeatherData.sys.sunrise*1000);
      console.log(`Sunrise after conversion to JS Date:${sunrise}` );
    }
    else {
      var openWeatherDataError = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log('Issue fetching from open weathermap. Status code: ' + openWeatherDataError.cod
        + 'Message: ' + openWeatherDataError.message);
    }
  });

  admin.firestore().collection('myCollectionPath')
    .doc('myDoc')
    .set(
      {
        'status': 'initiated',
        'initiationTime': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        'sunrise': admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(sunrise), 
      }
    )
    .then(doc => {
      return res.status(200).send('Stored Successfully');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(404).send({ error: 'unable to store', err });
    });
}
);
```

Expected result: Document to be saved successfully on Firestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to move the code that writes the `sunrise` to Firestore *into* the block that sets the value of `sunrise`.

So:

```
request(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log('Successfully retrieved from openweather');
      var openWeatherData = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(`Output from OpenWeather for Sunrise:${openWeatherData.sys.sunrise}` );
      var sunrise = new Date(openWeatherData.sys.sunrise*1000);
      console.log(`Sunrise after conversion to JS Date:${sunrise}` );

      admin.firestore().collection('myCollectionPath')
      .doc('myDoc')
      .set({
          'status': 'initiated',
          'initiationTime': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          'sunrise': admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(sunrise), 
      }).then(doc => {
        return res.status(200).send('Stored Successfully');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(404).send({ error: 'unable to store', err });
      });
    }
    else {
      var openWeatherDataError = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log('Issue fetching from open weathermap. Status code: ' + openWeatherDataError.cod
        + 'Message: ' + openWeatherDataError.message);
    }
  });
});
```

If this is still giving you issues, check what log output you get.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Felt silly. And goes to show I am a rusty programmer!